# compare two arrays based on a id and return a new array based on values

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, lodash

Trying to loop over two arrays and finding the codes for each, I might be missing some part. I need to construct a new array with this values, each id can be multiple times in the arrayB. Based on id in first array we have to match the id in a second array (arrayA) and get code

```
let arrayA=[
    {"breadcrumb":{id: "abdc4051"}, type:"details"},
    {"breadcrumb":{id: "abdc4052"}, type:"details"},

    let arrayB=[
    {"breadcrumb": {id: "abdc4051",code: "mike", length:"short"}},
    {"breadcrumb": {id: "abdc4051", code: "pohan", length:"long"}}, {"breadcrumb": {id: "abdc4052", code: "junior", length:"short"}}]

    let arrayC = [];
    // output expected
[{"id":"abdc4051", shortLength: "mike", longLength:"pohan"}, {"id":"abdc4052", shortLength: "Junior", longLength:"-"}]
    // tried this
    function isBiggerThan10(element, index, array) {
      return element > 10;
    }

    arrayA.forEach(function(element){
      arrayC.push({
      id:element.id,
      firstName:(arrayB.find(
        e => e.attributes.code==="mike")).breadCrumbs.shortLength,
      lastName:(arrayB.find(
        e => e.code==="pohan")).breadCrumbs.longlength
      })
    });

    console.log(arrayC);
```

Comment: I am not sur if I am able to understund your question proprely

Comment: [{"id":"abdc4051", firstName: "mike", lastName:"pohan"}, {"id":"abdc4052", firstName: "Junior", lastName:"-"}] this hsould be the ouput based on values of arrayA and arrayB

Comment: I feel like this same question is asked about thirty times a day

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution using the built in array methods. The steps are:

For each item in `arrayA`, perform the following:

- Find all items in `arrayB` that have the same ID (using `.filter`).
- Combine all those results into a single object, using default "-" for first and last name if not present (using `.reduce`).
- Put that into the results array (handled by using `.map` on `arrayA` in the first place).

```js
let arrayA = [
    {"breadcrumb":{id: "abdc4051"}, type:"details"},
    {"breadcrumb":{id: "abdc4052"}, type:"details"},
]

let arrayB = [
    {"breadcrumb": {id: "abdc4051", firstName: "mike"}},
    {"breadcrumb": {id: "abdc4051", lastName: "pohan"}},
    {"breadcrumb": {id: "abdc4052", firstName: "junior"}},
]

// output expected
// [
//   {"id":"abdc4051", firstName: "mike", lastName:"pohan"},
//   {"id":"abdc4052", firstName: "Junior", lastName:"-"},
// ]

const result = arrayA.map(itemA => {
    return arrayB
        .filter(itemB => itemB.breadcrumb.id === itemA.breadcrumb.id)
        .reduce((combo, item) => ({...combo, ...item.breadcrumb}), {firstName: "-", lastName: "-"})
});

console.log(result);
```

EDIT: Per edited question, you can modify the `reduce` function to see if the combo has `firstCode` set or not. If it does, then put the next `code` under the key `lastCode`, otherwise keep it as `firstCode`. This will base the first/last code on the order they appear in `arrayB`:

```js
let arrayA = [
    {"breadcrumb":{id: "abdc4051"}, type:"details"},
    {"breadcrumb":{id: "abdc4052"}, type:"details"},
]

let arrayB = [
    {"breadcrumb": {id: "abdc4051", code: "mike"}},
    {"breadcrumb": {id: "abdc4051", code: "pohan"}},
    {"breadcrumb": {id: "abdc4052", code: "junior"}},
]

// output expected
// [
//   {"id":"abdc4051", firstCode: "mike", lastCode:"pohan"},
//   {"id":"abdc4052", firstCode: "Junior", lastCode:"-"},
// ]

const result = arrayA.map(itemA => {
    return arrayB
        .filter(itemB => itemB.breadcrumb.id === itemA.breadcrumb.id)
        .reduce((combo, item) => ({...combo, [combo.firstCode === "-" ? "firstCode" : "lastCode"]: item.breadcrumb.code, id: itemA.breadcrumb.id}), {firstCode: "-", lastCode: "-"})
});

console.log(result);
```

EDIT 2: Per second edit, you can again modify the reduce to suit your needs:

```js
let arrayA = [
    {"breadcrumb":{id: "abdc4051"}, type:"details"},
    {"breadcrumb":{id: "abdc4052"}, type:"details"},
]

let arrayB = [
    {"breadcrumb": {id: "abdc4051", code: "mike", length: "short"}},
    {"breadcrumb": {id: "abdc4051", code: "pohan", length: "long"}},
    {"breadcrumb": {id: "abdc4052", code: "junior", length: "short"}},
]

// output expected
// [
//   {"id":"abdc4051", shortLength: "mike", longLength:"pohan"},
//   {"id":"abdc4052", shortLength: "junior", longLength:"-"},
// ]

const result = arrayA.map(itemA => {
    return arrayB
        .filter(itemB => itemB.breadcrumb.id === itemA.breadcrumb.id)
        .reduce((combo, item) => ({...combo, [item.breadcrumb.length + "Length"]: item.breadcrumb.code, id: itemA.breadcrumb.id}), {shortLength: "-", longLength: "-"})
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what if property name is same: let arrayA = [
    {"breadcrumb":{id: "abdc4051"}, type:"details"},
    {"breadcrumb":{id: "abdc4052"}, type:"details"},
]

let arrayB = [
    {"breadcrumb": {id: "abdc4051", firstName: "mike"}},
    {"breadcrumb": {id: "abdc4051", firstName: "pohan"}},
    {"breadcrumb": {id: "abdc4052", firstName: "junior"}},
] .. output should have firstname:mike and lastName:pohan

Comment: modified the question, sorry for missing that

Comment: Is the desired result in your edited question still what you want? It has `firstCode` and `lastCode` for the first item, but `firstName` and `lastName` for the second. Shouldn't they both be the one or the other?

Comment: no it is not giving the answer I expect. I need firstCode and lastCode to be there in same output object. like {id: abdc4051 , firstCode:mike, lasCode:pohan}

Answer (score 1):

Start a chain with `arrayB`. Use `_.map()` to get the content of `breadcrumb`, `_.groupBy()` by `id`. Use `_.pick()` with the ids of `arrayA` to get the groups you want. Map each group to required form using `_.transform()`:

```js
const arrayA=[{"breadcrumb":{"id":"abdc4051"},"type":"details"},{"breadcrumb":{"id":"abdc4052"},"type":"details"}];
const arrayB=[{"breadcrumb":{"id":"abdc4051","code":"mike","length":"short"}},{"breadcrumb":{"id":"abdc4051","code":"pohan","length":"long"}},{"breadcrumb":{"id":"abdc4052","code":"junior","length":"short"}}];
    
const result = _(arrayB)
  .map('breadcrumb') // unwrap breadcrumb
  .groupBy('id')
  .pick(arrayA.map((o) => _.get(o, 'breadcrumb.id'))) // get all groups that match arrayA ids
  .map((g, key) => _.transform(g, (acc, v) => { // transform each group to the requested form
    acc[`${v.length}Length`] = v.code;
  }, { key, shortLength: '-', longLength: '-' }))
  .value(); 
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```